# Calculations within a table

Tags: javascript

I have a table with 6 columns and 7 rows. I want to calculate cell[3] * cell[4] = sum in cell[5]. I want this calculation to be made on each row. How can I access the values in those columns and perform the calculation?

Right now I have only been able to make calculation of how many rows its inside the table. This calculation have to be part of the solution as the number of rows can increase/decrease.

```
function countRows() {
    var totalRowCount = 0;
    var rowCount = 0;
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        totalRowCount++;
        if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One way to get the column in each row is: `rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]` for getting the 3rd cell and `rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3]` for getting the 4th.

Comment: is using jQuery okay?

Comment: I´d rather not use Jquery right now, but only simple js.

Comment: isn't *cell[3]*cell[4]* supposed to be a ***product*** rather than *sum*?

Comment: Yes, you are right, Im looking for the product.

Comment: @guskansma : than you might want to check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59454820/11299053) below, followed by the live-snippet. If that solves your problem, you may accept that.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you didn't want to use jquery, but it should be easy to translate this into nonJquery anyway:

https://jsfiddle.net/7zera5qt/

```
$('tbody tr').each(function(){
    const $row = $(this);
  const $fourth = $row.find('td').eq(3);
  const $fifth = $row.find('td').eq(4);

  const sum = Number($fourth.text()) * Number($fifth.text());

  $row.find('td').eq(5).text(sum);
})
```

Iterate over each row, find the fourth and fifth tds in that row, get their text value, sum them up how you want, and put it in the fifth td.